# How to remove properties from jason object using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a Json Object (Dict) like below:

```
{name = 'John',
 address = '123 bb',
 age = '40'
 children:[{ name ="smith',
             address ='458 ff',
             age = '25',
             grand_children [{name ="smith',
                              address ='458 ff',
                               age = '25'},
                              {name ="smith',
                              address ='458 ff',
                               age = '25'}],
           { name ="smith',
             address ='458 ff',
             age = '25',
             grand_children [{name ="smith',
                              address ='458 ff',
                               age = '25'},
                              {name ="smith',
                              address ='458 ff',
                               age = '25'}]]}
```

is there a easy way of remove property one at a time

e.g remove names (one at a time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code for removing a property from the object (recursively from its children too.)

```py
def remove_property(obj, prop_name):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if prop_name in obj:
            del obj[prop_name]
        for value in obj.values():
            remove_property(value, prop_name)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            remove_property(item, prop_name)

# Example usage
data = {
    'name': 'John',
    'address': '123 bb',
    'age': '40',
    'children': [
        {
            'name': 'smith',
            'address': '458 ff',
            'age': '25',
            'grand_children': [
                {
                    'name': 'smith',
                    'address': '458 ff',
                    'age': '25'
                },
                {
                    'name': 'smith',
                    'address': '458 ff',
                    'age': '25'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'name': 'smith',
            'address': '458 ff',
            'age': '25',
            'grand_children': [
                {
                    'name': 'smith',
                    'address': '458 ff',
                    'age': '25'
                },
                {
                    'name': 'smith',
                    'address': '458 ff',
                    'age': '25'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

remove_property(data, 'name')

print(data)
```

OR

if you just want to delete a property (not recursively) use the `del` keyword.